# What can cause a wheel new wheel bearing to fail after 2 weeks of use?

Tags: chevrolet, bearing, cavalier

I replaced both front wheel bearings on my 2002 Chevy Cavalier about a year ago and again just 2 weeks ago.

One of them has already gone out again.  Is it possible that the bearing is just bad or is it possible that something else is wrong that is causing the bearings to go bad so quickly?

I'm replacing the whole hub assembly each time and not packing the bearings myself.

Comment: How do you know it's the wheel bearing which is going bad?

Comment: It sounds and acts like a bad wheel bearing.  It started out make noise only at around 30 mph when breaking and with in a couple of days and quickly escalated to a loud noise at higher speeds.  When I turn to the left the noise gets quieter and louder when turning to the right.  I haven't checked if it's got any play yet though.

Comment: One way to dramaticly shorten the life of a wheel bearing is too use a hammer to replace them. The bearings should be press fitted(hydraulic press) even on taper roller bearing tracks. Over-tightening them, or not tighten them enough (torque wrench) can also cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my lug nuts came loose and the wheel wobbling back and forth sounded like a bad wheel bearing.

I know I tightened everything up when I was done.  It's possible that the wheel or the rotor wasn't seeded correctly though and loosened up once I started driving.

It should have been the first thing that I checked.